# clearInterval on hover after ready page

Tags: jquery

Good morning, I ask for help for my code. It works but i would like to load the content right away and not after hover-in and hover-out.

How can I fix it? thank you

`

```
<script>
function aggiornatabella(){
$('#tabella').load('pres_tl_admin_ajax_load.php'); // carica il contenuto dal file e lo mette nel div #tabella
}

$(document).hover(
function(){ // quando è tutto pronto...
clearInterval(timer);
          },
function(){
timer = setInterval(aggiornatabella, 1000); // ogni secondo aggiorna la tabella
          }
                );

</script>
<? print"<div id=\"tabella\"></div>"; ?>
```

[SOLVED]
This is the solution, thank you all

`

```
<script>
function aggiornatabella(){
$('#tabella').load('pres_tl_admin_ajax_load.php'); // carica il contenuto dal file e lo mette nel div #tabella
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    var interval = setInterval(aggiornatabella , 2000);
$('#tabella').hover(function (ev) {
    clearInterval(interval);
}, function (ev) {
    interval = setInterval(aggiornatabella , 2000);
});
}); 
</script>
<? print"<div id=\"tabella\"></div>"; ?>
```

`

`

Comment: Directly invoke the method, i.e. `$(function(){ aggiornatabella(); });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).hover(
    function(){ // quando è tutto pronto...
       clearInterval(timer);
    },
    function(){
      timer = setInterval(aggiornatabella, 1000); // ogni secondo aggiorna la tabella
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: Sorry I was wrong, I want clearInterval on hover-in and setinterval on hover-out But the page loads only after hover-in and hover-out While I would like to charge immediately

Answer (score 0):

Most of your JavaScript code is just nonsense. You only really need one line of it. I also added a wrapper so that this will load when the document is ready, instead of straight away  where it might not work:

```js
$(function() {
    $('#tabella').load('pres_tl_admin_ajax_load.php');
}
```

You can remove the rest of the JavaScript.

Comment: Sorry I was wrong,
I want clearInterval on hover-in and setinterval on hover-out 
But the page loads only after hover-in and hover-out While I would like to charge immediately